# postgres create "delete_expired_rows"- trigger

Tags: postgresql, syntax

I have some code that does not delete rows when there sys_period ends and I move them to a historic table. So I would like to make a trigger that after an update of a row looks at all the rows and removes each row that does where the sys_period end is not infinity. My initial guess is the following. But I'm not a master in SQL syntax can you help me?

```
CREATE TRIGGER {0}_delete_old_rows_trigger
        AFTER UPDATE ON "{0}"
        BEGIN 
            DELETE FROM "{0}"
            WHERE upper_inf(sys_period) is FALSE
        END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it could be handled with a query rewrite rule:

```
CREATE RULE upd_to_del AS ON UPDATE TO tab
   WHERE NOT upper_inf(NEW.sys_period)
   DO INSTEAD
      DELETE FROM tab WHERE id = NEW.id;
```